# How to ignore timestamp of the files while performing diff operation

Tags: tar, timestamps, diff

I created a file named `me.txt` with text

```
This is dummy text
```

Then I made a TAR out of it and named `me.txt.tar`.

Now after a minute I again created a file with exactly same name and the text (basically I just did `touch me.txt`), then made TAR out of it called `me2.txt.tar`.

Technically both the tars have same file with same file contents but time of creation of file `me.txt` is different. But the diff tool is saying:

```
Binary files me.txt.tar and me2.txt.tar differ
```

This is because of reason of timestamp difference of file creation. But I just want to compare the contents of file and need to ignore the timestamp & hence I expect no output from the diff.

Please help me to ignore the timestamp of the files inside a TAR or JAR etc. as my concern is towards the contents of files.

- The commands I used are :

  ```
  $ echo "This is dummy text" > me.txt
  $ tar -cvf me.txt.tar me.txt
  (After 1 minute or so..)
  $ touch me.txt 
  $ tar -cvf me2.txt.tar me.txt
  $ diff me.txt.tar me2.txt.tar
  ```
- output:

  ```
  Binary files me.txt.tar and me2.txt.tar differ
  ```

Even `diffoscope` gives similar output.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100889/how-to-compare-two-tar-archives-including-file-content-new-removed-files-syml and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930300/how-to-compare-two-tar-archives-including-file-content-new-removed-files-syml and https://superuser.com/a/125399/1076830

Comment: @IbnFulan, Thanks for replying. But, I expect no output from diff as the contents of file are same..

Comment: The contents of the files you’re asking `diff` to compare *aren’t* the same. If you want to compare `me.txt`, you need to compare that; `me.tar` and `me2.tar` don’t have the same contents.

Comment: @StephenKitt, This is just a sample tar file, in reality, I have a tars & jars with thousands of files in them & I cant manually diff on each of the file.. Can you please suggest me a solution to ignore timestamp of files in tar or jar?.. Thanks alot for replying

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to compare the contents of the files in your archives, and not the metadata in the archives themselves, you should compare the contents. Assuming the files are stored in the same order in all archives,

```
diff -u <(tar xOf me.txt.tar) <(tar xOf me2.txt.tar)
```

For JARs, you’d use `unzip`:

```
diff -u <(unzip -c file1.jar) <(unzip -c file2.jar)
```

Comment: Hey Stephan, Thanks for the answer. The above method is working fine for tars i.e., 1st command works!! But the second command i.e., on jars, is not working.. (Output says "binary files differ" but they are actually not)

Comment: What does `diffoscope --exclude-directory-metadata=recursive` says is the difference between your JARs?

Comment: @stephan this option is not working!!

Comment: My name is Stephen, not Stephan. What do you mean by “is not working”? Does it produce an error message?

Comment: It says - ignored explicit argument 'recursive' & if I remove recursive, its still giving diffoscope output while it should not

Comment: But if I use this - [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100960/491082), its working but  I'm not intended to use not so safe AVFS!!

Comment: Why do you keep saying that `diffoscope` shouldn’t produce output? The files you’re comparing (the archives) *are* different. If you show me the output I might be able to help you find a way to compare the contents.

Comment: `--rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      163 b- defN 21-Aug-31 12:08 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (red color )
`+-rw-r--r--  2.0 unx      163 b- defN 21-Sep-02 04:38 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`  (green color)

Comment: Can you please comment on AVFS, like is it a good option to use, considering using it to verify integrity of builds?

Comment: Very late comment, but I was able to get the second option working for JAR files by using `-p` instead of `-c` in the embedded `unzip` commands.